# Button doesn't Enable after IsEnabled Binding updates

Tags: c#, wpf, button, binding

I got a class called **Document**

```cs
public class Document : INotifyPropertyChanged
{                  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }             

    private string oldId;
    public string OldId
    {
        get { return oldId; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { 
            id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("HasChanged");
        }
    }

    private string path;
    public string Path
    {
        get { return path; }
        set { path = value; }
    }

    public bool HasChanged
    {
        get { return id != oldId; }
    }

    public Document(string id, string path)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.oldId = id;
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

I got a List of **Documents** in my WPF code behind, **items** is an ItemsControl in my Form.

```cs
AddItem("a", "b");
AddItem("b", "b");
AddItem("c", "b");
AddItem("d", "b");
```

...

```cs
private void AddItem(string key, string value)
{
    items.Items.Add(new Document(key, value));
}
```

My WPF looks as follows:

```cs
<ItemsControl x:Name="items" AlternationCount="100">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox 
                    Text="{Binding Id}"

                    PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"></TextBox>
                <Button 
                    Grid.Column="1" 

                    IsEnabled="{Binding HasChanged}"
                    Content="Ok"

                    Click="ButtonOk_Click"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As you can guess, I want to enable the Button, when the text in the tb has altered from the original text.

[image: All good]

Problem is that after I change the text in one of the textboxes, the button doesn't enable.

[image: After Edit, notice that the button is still disabled]

If I click the button, it changes to being enabled.

[image: After the first click, button updates]

If I click it again, it executes the OnClick.

[image: After the second click, OnClick executes]

What has do be changed, that the button updates on keypress?

Keep in mind that I use the ItemControl to generate the button on-the-fly, so updating it from code-behind over it's name is not possible.

I don't use a ViewModel and I wouldn't want to add one, as this project is to small to use the any ViewModel based Design Pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What your experiencing is probably because the default Binding for TextBoxes' `Text` property has `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`.

Which means that your `Id` property is not being updated until the `TextBox` loses keyboard focus (when you click the disabled button). Probably, if you click another `TextBox`, the button would get enabled just the same.

You can change this behavior in your XAML, like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"></TextBox>
```